# Serial call to same AJAX function only returns data from last call

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

I have three div elements, and I want to populate each element with its own content. I call the same AJAX (very generic) function each time, sending the name of the div id as a parameter:

```
//left-right rectangle content
var rl = getContent("rightLeft");   

//bottom content
var br = getContent("bottomRectangle");

//top content
var rtr = getContent("rightTopRectangle");
```

If I do an alert(http.responseText) within the AJAX function, I get the correct html content from the remote page. (In fact, if I add an alert, it seems to "slow" the function down so that my content is returned properly each time I call it, but who wants alerts on their web page?).

But, without the alerts, the above calls will only properly process the last call. So, in the above sequence of calls, only the last div, where id="rightTopRectangle" will be filled with the html retrieved from the AJAX call. The previous two calls don't populate their divs with the AJAX retrieved html. If I shake up the order of the calls, it will always be the last AJAX call that works.

I get the feeling the problem has something to do with the asynchronous part, where the previous calls don't have enough time to process the request before the AJAX function is requested again and again.

Here's the AJAX function:

```
function getContent(element){
    var url = "ajax/getcontent.php?cid="+element; //alert(url);
    http.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (http.readyState==4 && http.status==200){ //alert(http.responseText);
            var response = http.responseXML.documentElement;
            callback(element,http.responseText);
        }
    }
    http.open("GET",url,true);
    http.send();        
}
```

The function named "callback" (it works fine) looks like this:

```
function callback(e,c){
    document.getElementById(e).innerHTML = "<div style=\"line-height:"+ document.getElementById(e).offsetHeight +"px;margin:0px auto 0px auto;text-align:center;\" >" + unescape(c) + "</div>";
}
```

UPDATE: This works now. I added one line to my getContent function:

```
function getContent(element){
    var http = createRequestObject(); /*After Tej's answer, I took this line out 
    of the root of my script and placed it here, within the function, in order to 
    instantiate a new http object each time I call this function, so that they all 
    operate independently of one another*/
    var url = "ajax/getcontent.php?cid="+element; //alert(url);
    http.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (http.readyState==4 && http.status==200){
            var response = http.responseXML.documentElement;
            callback(element,http.responseText);
        }
    }
    http.open("GET",url,true);
    http.send();        
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are reusing some ajax request object for all three requests; I certainly dont see you creating a new instance of `http` for each `getContent` call.

Comment: Tejs, yes. Do you think I should not reuse the same ajax request? I should re-write the same ajax request code 3 times?

Comment: You should create a new `XmlHttpRequest` for each call. The code used for responding to the call doesn't need to be duplicated.

Comment: Thanks to Tejs: I removed the global 
    var http = createRequestObject(); 
...and placed it as the first line within the getContent(element) function, and now everything works.

Thank you, Tejs!

Comment: @Tejs you should post that as an answer

Comment: AJAX cannot be reaused. It's a one-time request-response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-using the same `XmlHttpRequest` for all of your ajax requests; this leads to the last request always winning because the others have been overwritten. You should instead create a new ajax request for each call.

```
 http = CreateAjaxRequest();
 http.onreadystatechange = function() { ... }
 // etc
```

Answer (score 0):

you should pass `element` parameter to your onreadystatechange function, try this,

```
req.onreadystatechange = function (el) {
    return function() {
      if (http.readyState==4 && http.status==200){ //alert(http.responseText);
          var response = http.responseXML.documentElement;
          callback(el,http.responseText);
      }
    };
}(element);
```